# Ember Cli undefined method 'eve' raphael js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, requirejs, raphael, ember-cli

i'm developing an ember app using ember-cli and i'm trying to use Raphael.js but when i put it in my page with

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
```

it will return

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: eve is not defined
```

i read that Raphael.js have problem with RequireJS, could be related?

someone have used it successfully?

thanks a lot

Comment: As a start, is it possible to try with the latest release? `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js`

Comment: i've done that but the error remains.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. It's something to do with Ember CLI because I can copy and paste the source into my console on any other page than an Ember CLI app and receive no complaints of this error

Comment: Not tried yet but on github (https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/890#issuecomment-53135967) they answered me
@sunrize920

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, I don't know if the culprit is the same. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`

Comment: I have the same issue here Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined